# Haskell: Can type variables be used within function definition?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a problem relating to the Haskell type system. This is not the first time I have encountered the type system's limitations. I will omit my project details and use a simplified example. Here is some code:

```
-- Works
foo :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a
foo = minBound

-- "ambiguous" constraint:
-- 'a' has no occurrences in type declaration
bar :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => Int
bar = fromEnum minBound

-- Too much information in return
-- but I can show haskell the appropriate type of 'min'
baz :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => (a, Int)
baz = let min = minBound
    in (min, someFunction . fromEnum $ min)

-- Type constraint 'a' not ambiguous
--     (or at least that isn't the compiler error message)
-- but Haskell doesn't know which 'minBound' to use
barrer :: (Bounded a, Enum a) => a
barrer = let min = minBound -- <- min's type is ambiguous
    in toEnum . someFunction . fromEnum $ min
```

What I am trying to achieve is similar to `barrer`: First, use the `minBound` value specific to type `a` and 'cast' it to an integer. In my project, I proceed to transform this integer (to avoid intermediate arithmetic overflows when using type `a`) and 'cast' them back to type `a` (after a bit of `mod` magic). How can I tell Haskell the appropriate type of `minBound`? Is it possible?

The obvious solution is to add an annotation of `minBound :: a`. This would also fix `bar`. The problem: The type variable `a` seems to be out of scope in the function definition, as Haskell freshens `minBound :: a` to `minBound a0` in the error message. Is there a way to do this type of annotation?

One bad hack I used was to constrain the type of the `minBound` call by including it in the function's return type, a la `baz`. This solution is not ideal. Does anyone have some advise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [ScopedTypeVariables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables) extension solves exactly your problem. The page also provides some alternative solutions (`asTypeOf` and `undefined` arguments).

Comment: "Scoped type variables" - Exactly what I wanted. And said so much more succinctly than my title!

Comment: How would you even do this with asTypeOf and undefined? It seems to me that you can't ever get a value of type `a` to point asTypeOf at, because none are either passed in or returned from this function. You could only get hold of one via scoped type variables, at which point you no longer need asTypeOf or undefined.

Comment: @amalloy Because `asTypeOf` never actually evaluates its second argument, just uses it for type inference, you can tie it into knots like this: ``barrer = let min = minBound `asTypeOf` result; result = toEnum . someFunction . fromEnum $ min in result``

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I get that you don't need an actual value for the asTypeOf, but you can't even get a handle to its type. Here, the return type of the function is `Int`, not `a`, and so you can't just use `asTypeOf result` to get something of type `a`. Maybe I'm just not understanding your suggestion; can you write a specific function that has the OP's type signature, without scoped type variables and no ambiguity?

Comment: That is, given OP's type signature, `asTypeOf minBound result` just gets you `minBound :: Int`, not `minBound :: a`.

Comment: @amalloy Oh, that's the signature of `bar`, I interpreted OP as being more interested in `barrer`. I note there's a bit of unfortunate phrasing but they are doing more to the integer after constructing it.

Comment: Ah. Indeed, `barrer` is not a big deal to do. But I think `bar` still is impossible without scoped type variables, right?

Comment: @amalloy Yeah, In fact I don't think even scoped type variables help for that one.